# Updating child and parent records using Workflows and Processes

Tags: workflow, process-builder

I am not sure but my understanding is that using a workflow, you cannot update a parent record from a a child. You can however update a child object from a parent. Is this correct? Also, using process builder, can you do both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes PB can do both.

You can update a child record from a parent in a WF by using a formula. Something like:

```
parent__r.field__c
```

I went to find docs for you via google and there are so many results that are useful that I just can't link to them all. I recommend googling for more info.

Comment: But you cannot update parent record from a child record using WF right?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: I'd also like to add trial and error is your friend here. This is the type of question you can answer by just trying to do it and see what happens.